# Where do I run neutral from/to when replacing a SPST switch with one that requires neutral?

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch

I have a basic/good understanding of electrical wiring and I'm taking all necessary precautions. My research indicates that the old setup does not have a neutral going to the box, and that since the new one requires it, I need to run one. From where to where? I'm not so concerned with being code-compliant, I'm only concerned with getting it working. A ground wire is present in the box if that makes a difference. There are no other circuits nearby that I can splice into. The switch controls an overhead light.

Comment: I'm curious why your switch requires a neutral - you should always be switching the hot.  Does it has some sort of GFCI feature?

Comment: @Comintern motion sensors, timers and automation switches typically require a neutral.

Comment: The codes are there for safety so when you say "I don't care about code compliance", you're really saying "I don't care how safe it is". It's not just *your* safety, but the safety of the next guy that owns your house, and makes an electrical modification that relies on your work being code compliant.

Comment: You do not know my situation at all. For all you know, I'm asking a purely theoretical question. Your response is off-topic. You do not address the question that was asked, and in fact address a point that was explicitly noted as irrelevant to my question.

Comment: @Parker - Regardless of your own situation, it does not seem that asking for answers that disregard safety (and code compliance) are appropriate for this site since some people may see the question and answers and choose the unsafe route without understanding the risks to themselves and others. If anything, an amateur should be more stringent about compliance than a professional. Purely theoretical questions that don't relate to an actual problem you are facing are specifically [off topic](http://diy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), so I assumed that this was a real problem you were facing.

Comment: You should actually look at the wiring first to check for a neutral wire. Some ways of wiring the switch do have the neutral going "through" the switch box.

Answer (score 3):

Many switches that need a neutral have equivalent versions from other brands that do not need a neutral. You may be able to find a switch that has the functionality you want without doing additional wiring. While current code requires a neutral at switches, you are allowed to replace existing switches without rewiring if the neutral is not present.

If that does not meet your needs, you will have to run a neutral wire. Assuming that your wiring is not in conduit (very unlikely), you will need to run a new 3 wire non-metallic (NM) cable to the switch (white/black/red/bare). The correct way to do this is from the overhead light fixture, replacing the 2 wire cable that currently runs to the switch.

Once the cable is run, disconnect the old switch wires and use the red and black from the new cable for the switched hot line.

SIDE NOTE: Under **NO** circumstances should you use the ground as a neutral.

Comment: 'You will need to run a new 3 wire non-metallic cable...from the overhead light fixture, [using] the red and black from the new cable."  Okay, but what about the neutral? Where does that go?

Comment: At the fixture box, the neutral in the new wire is attached directly to the other neutrals (at least the source and the fixture neutral; there may be others tied in there). On the switch end, it is attached to the neutral terminal. In general, all neutrals on a given circuit are tied together, and the hot lines are separate or switched as needed.

Comment: While non-neutral versions of many "smart"  switches (i.e. motion sensing, remote control, etc) may be available, they don't always work well with modern low-energy lightbulbs since they typically rely on leakage current through the bulb which can lead to the low energy light flashing randomly while "turned off" and the switch itself may work erratically or not at all. Sometimes the only solution is to run a neutral, or forgo  the smart  switch.

Comment: Must I run the neutral from the switch to the fixture, or may I run it to any neutral I can find on the same circuit? Not that there is one especially accessible, but the one at the fixture is particularly unaccessible.

Comment: It must be from the same circuit. All nuetrals in a single circuit are supposed to be connected, so any should do.